# Disable button if no date is selected from datepicker material

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a button and a Datepicker in Material Angular. The button is disabled as default, Because a user has to pickup a date from the datepicker. But even if a date is selected the  button stays disabled.

The template for datepicker looks like this:

```
  <div>
      <mat-form-field class="search-field-input md-datepicker-input-container">
        <input
          matInput
          readonly
          required
          [matDatepicker]="picker1"
          placeholder="start datum"
          [(ngModel)]="startDate"
          (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

And the button looks like this:

```
  <button
        [disabled]=" !buttonFilterDisabled || !startDate "
        mat-raised-button
        color="accent"
        class="Button"
        (click)="searchFor()"
      >
        Filter
      </button>
```

And the onchange looks like this:

```
  onChange() {
    this.buttonFilterDisabled = true;
  }
```

So my question is: How to enable the button when a valid date is selected from the datepicker?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `&&` operator instead of `||`:

```
<button
    [disabled]=" !buttonFilterDisabled && !startDate "
    mat-raised-button
    color="accent"
    class="Button"
    (click)="searchFor()"
  >
    Filter
  </button>
```

[As MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Logical AND (&&)  expr1 && expr2  If expr1 can be converted to true,
>   returns expr2; else, returns expr1.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton what value do you have in `startDate` while initializing? could you add your code? or maybe create a stackblitz example.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I am glad that it helped to you! :) If you feel that the reply helps to you, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [What should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)